# Python Eggs on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, virtualenv, pip

Usually I would use `virtualenv` and `pip` for deployment of web applications. With Google App Engine this doesn't work, because all `import` statement are relative to directory of the application.

The most common approach I saw was to simply copy the packages from `site-packages` to the directory of the application. This involves manual work and is error-prone.

Another approach was to changes `install_lib` and `install_scripts` in `~/.pydisutils.cfg`, but this doesn't allow me to use `pip` in my home directory simultaneously.

Do you have any suggestions for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems manually adding the `virtualenv` to `sys.path` solves the problem for me at the moment:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), 'dev.env/lib/python2.5/site-packages/'))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use easy_install instead of pip you can run it with the `--install-dir` argument to specify a non-default installation directory.