# Trouble Importing LinkedIn Library w/ Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, import, linkedin-api, google-api-python-client

So I've installed the GoogleAppEngine on my MacBookPro.
I've installed [python-linkedin](https://github.com/ozgur/python-linkedin/blob/master/README.md) using **pip install**.
I've created a project inside GoogleAppEngine and I've gotten a "Hello, World!" to appear.
As soon as I make a

```
from linkedin import linkedin
```

it fails.
The stack trace looks like this and I'm getting really frustrated...

```
File "/Users/user/Developer/project/main.py", line 18, in <module>
    from linkedin import linkedin
ImportError: No module named linkedin
```

Please let me know if there's any other information that I can add that can help you help me.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python Eggs on Google App Engine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4530183/python-eggs-on-google-app-engine)

Comment: This type of question is asked every few days, just search for import pip  for appengine.  Its very useful to read the docs, about the python runtime in appengine it also tells you what to do. https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/#Python_The_sandbox